# Is Calculus AB/BC a 'bad course?'

Tags: calculus

preface: I took AB and not BC but I feel both are similar in nature.

By bad course, I mean that I feel as though [Calculus AB/BC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AP_Calculus) sets students up for 'failure,'

for starters, how successful are BC students in the future multivariable course?

To get a 5 in BC, one needs to pass with almost a 60% of questions correct on the exam. The exam is also all computation (which to be fair is much of Calculus II anyway), but because a lot of the exam is computations, proofs are magically handwaved or ignored in favor of computation (which gives students a bad impression of what math really is). For example, delta-epsilon is never touched on and so when I first encountered delta-epsilon, I was very confused.

Comment: *(This pertains to the U.S.)* Aside from honors level college courses, you're also not going to see much in the way of proofs in college Calculus 1 (differential calculus) or Calculus 2 (integral calculus). Typically, proofs are postponed to advanced calculus (traditionally this has been a Junior-Senior level 2-semester sequence) or in undergraduate real analysis.

Comment: I'll say that faculty at my college are not happy about being forced by administration to give college credit for these courses.

Comment: that's not true, I went to a 'mediocre' school and, in calc I, we had to prove all the limit laws, linear approximation, IVT, MVT, limit of sinx/x, l'hopital. In calc II, we had to prove arc length, parametric and polar work, sequences (limit n^(1/n)), the Taylor series, etc.

Comment: @TommiBrander: I've edited the question to include a Wikipedia link on [Advanced Placement Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AP_Calculus). For more background, see also the Wikipedia article on the [Advanced Placement program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Placement) in general.

Comment: I took AB/BC and I don't remember ever encountering delta-epsilon in my multivariable calculus courses. Mine focused mostly on computation rather than proofs, though (it was at an engineering school, so pure math was less of a focus), so that's probably why.

Comment: in multivariable calculus, you still need to prove: Taylor's theorem, change of variables and the 4 fundamental theorems of vector calculus. Fubini's theorem and Clairaut's theorem are handwaved away by promising "nice enough" functions.

Comment: There is a middle ground between requiring epsilonics and completely ignoring proofs. We can have analysis without going all the way into the technical details. I think the question is whether or not we see questions which are novel and require thinking based on concepts. Or, is the expectation of the course that the tests be just like the homework with almost everything falling into the PSQ category. I have students who are genuinely confused when I lecture in the style of discussion as opposed to: "here is a problem... here is how you solve it". AP test format does tend towards thinking deep

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes the AP exam is bad and not an adequate substitute for a rigorous college class at, say, a state flagship university.  This is for two main reasons:

1. The exam allows calculators and the calculators are really good at Calculus, so you can answer many of the questions just by learning how to get the calculator to do calculus.
2. The grade range is too small.  As you point out a 5 is 60%, which at most strong colleges would be a failing grade.  Of course the vast majority of students go to schools that are weaker than state flagships so maybe a 5 is an A at most schools, but the cutoff for credit at my university should be something more like a 6 rather than a 4.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think there is traditionally much need for epsilon-delta in third semester calculus.  After all, it is not a real analysis course.
2. When I took calc in the 80s, there was a short section on epsilon-delta.  But who cares.  It's not like you need it to do hard calc problems.  Euler didn't.
3. The 60% is more troubling, but all that said, I bet ETS has plenty of statistics to back up the idea that a 5 is like an A for a typical (GA Tech, not Cal Tech) calc course.

Comment: The typical AP BC calculus course is nothing like as demanding as the typical first year calculus course in a university like Ga Tech. Students who place out of first year calculus are often done a disservice, because they never learn calculus well, as they would have had they taken the first-year course.

Comment: The remark "When I took calc in the 80s, there was a short section on epsilon-delta. But who cares. It's not like you need it to do hard calc problems. Euler didn't." seems to me absurd. Any serious use of calculus requires understanding it's basic definitions. Students who never understand epsilon-delta argumentation have not developed basic intellectual skills adequately to understand things like ordinary differential equations that make heavy use of calculus. They may not make rigorous arguments later, but they do need to know how to think.

Comment: If my Calculus students understood calculus as well as Euler did, I'd be thrilled!  I actually agree with this answer on point 2.  What I disagree with is point 3, which is factually incorrect, and honestly somewhat insulting to Georgia Tech which is a very strong university.

Comment: Dan, I took BC, using an AP text (Thomas and Finney, the book you see in Stand and Deliver).  But the content was almost the same as the college edition of the text.  I had zero problems after validating out of 2 semesters of calc at USNA with a 5 in further math and science courses.  I suspect USNA and GA Tech are similar caliber.  Again, I am the opposite of an ETS defender.  But I would also not assume that individual snipes on the Internet are the same as their systemic psychometric evaluation and proof that a 5 is equivalent to an A in a standard calc course.

Comment: The problem here is that since the range is cut off, *some* 5's are equivalent to an A, but *some* 5's are equivalent to B's and some to C's.  I bet you got a pretty high 5.

Comment: OK.  Probably talking about how students with a 4 compare to students who got a B in frosh calc would be more helpful.

Comment: https://www.maa.org/external_archive/columns/launchings/launchings_06_09.html#Q3

Comment: See also table in https://www.thoughtco.com/ap-calculus-bc-score-information-786947  Most of the schools offered two semesters calc validation for a 4.

Comment: Dan, regarding ODEs, I have 4 common ODE texts on my shelf.  Standard books used at USNA, NU, etc.  None of them require the use of epsilon delta to learn diffyQs.  Most classic ODE solution methods were developed very fast after the calculus itself (before 1700).  The people doing that and using the diffyQs for applications afterwards, did not have modern analytical theory.  See this retrospective:  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.112.3646&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Another discussion of AP calculus efficacy (long and with references to other studies).  Bottom line is that a 4 in BC is reasonable prep to move to 3rd semester calculus at schools like Berkley, USNA, etc.  Students who do, perform about the same as students who got B's in intro calc sequence at the college and then went to calc 3.  https://www.macalester.edu/~bressoud/misc/RoleOfCalculus.pdf

Comment: @guest -- Your comment with the macalester link would make a good answer.

Comment: +1 but I disagree that epsilon-delta formalism is useless for engineering majors. As to point 3 about 60%, I couldn't agree more. It's indeed very troubling but the worst thing is many modern students don't even know precalc properly, and that's a catastrophe. It's almost impossible to deal with it. It's so bad that I consider math education was much better 20-30 years ago. At the same time AP exams aren't bad, although they aren't perfect either. Downvotes here ain't a surprise for me either. All people care for is rote-learning, formalism and citation indexes. They don't care about science.

Comment: I was unable to find “Berkeley”, “USNA”, “Naval”, or “Navy” when searching the linked document.  @guest, could you reference a page number or at least which article you’re referring to?